# CopyTo HttpWebRequest stream creates memory increasing

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, memory-leaks, stream

I have a WCF Rest Post function (WebInvoke) that gets from the webclient stream of data (From Javascript File API) and sends this stream to another server by using HttpWebRequest.
When there are lots of calls the memory increasing so high that after a while the w3wp process consumes too much memory and there's a recycle to this application pool.
The problematic line is the CopyTo function

```
SendToOtherServer(Stream fileContents)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("the other server address");
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    fileContents.CopyTo(dataStream);
    // send ... (GetResponse/BeginGetResponse)
    dataStream.Dispose();
}
```

I tried to use using, but it didn't help

```
using (Stream destStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    using (Stream sourceStream = fileContents)
    {
       sourceStream.CopyTo(destStream);
    }
}
```

I tried to call in the end of the function to:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

everything becomes so slow but the memory don't increase so much.
But of course it's impractical.

Is it a memory leak? how can I dispose it right away?

Comment: Yes and No.  The GC will not delete an item that has a link to the item.  The managed c# code for each object has a count of number of external links to the object.  A object will only be disposed when the external link count goes to zero.  Your code may of created a link to the object and until the link is broken the object will not get disposed.  GC runs in background mode and only runs when memory usage gets high.  So if a higher priority task is running the GC may not run until the memory is absolutely needed.

Comment: @jdweng "The managed c# code for each object has a count of number of external links to the object. A object will only be disposed when the external link count goes to zero" is false. Standard GC does not do reference-counting, it does mark-sweep, so it goes to each item and recursively marks the objects pointed to by its fields as "seen".

Comment: Why are you using WebRequest and not the newer HttpClient?

Comment: @Charlieface : Then without counting you can get exceptions when GC disposes an item and it is then used.  I've never seen this happen in c#.  Also seen lots of cases that GC did not work until I broke an external link

Comment: @Charlieface : It is still an array of links and the array has a count.

Comment: @jdweng "only runs when memory usage gets high" - this is also wrong. GC will run when system has low remaining physical memory or the managed heap goes above a certain level (and that level is variable)

Comment: @jdweng There is no "count" that is being maintained. Every time GC runs, it goes down the reference tree and marks things as seen. It's either seen or not, there is no count.